# HTML tag showing as a string

Tags: javascript, html

Please check my code and let me know what I am doing wrong

```
 $('ul.ne.elBulletList.listSize1.listImage32.listBorder0 li').text(function(_, text) {
        // return (); // just the original requirement
        str = `<div class="heading">`;
        str += text.split('-', 1).pop();
        str += `</div><div class=text">`;
        str += text.split('-').pop();
        str += `</div>`;
        // console.dir(str));
        return innerText = str; // with whitespace removed
      });
```

Html is displaying as a plain text. can anyone tell me what is wrong I am doing.

Thanks

Comment: You do not want to use `.text()` function but `.html` function [check here](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: you're using backticks for your strings too .... (not sure how realistically it's an issue, but single quotes are pref. Double quotes if you must)

Comment: I am getting the same result when I use innerHTML or innerText

Comment: when I am using return $(this).html(str), then it return object

Answer (score 5):

> [`.text( text )`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
>
> We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as
>   necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls
>   the DOM method .createTextNode(), does not interpret the string as
>   HTML.

---

> [`.html( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
>
> A function returning the HTML content to set

Comment: when I am using return $(this).html(str), then it return object and also same with .text()

Comment: @SanjaySamant That's because both `.html(...)` and `.text(...)` return the object being modified.  You can see this if you observe the documentation linked in the answer.

Comment: @SanjaySamant You call the `.html(...)` method on the element you want to populate?  That's what it *does*.

Comment: but it returns object object and can not handle with JSON.stringify

Comment: @SanjaySamant — I have no idea what the relevance of the return value of `html(...)` is. You don't use it in your question (nor do you use the return value of `.text(...)`). You don't use `JSON.stringify` in your question. If you have a *new* question, then [ask a *new* question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @SanjaySamant You are using `.text(..)` in your question.  **Replace it with `.html(...)` instead.**  I really do not understand the confusion here.  The return value from `.html(...)` is not relevant, and I don't understand why it is being brought up.